# How to do multiple file validation in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I know there is an activity called validation in the azure data factory to validate one file.
However, I want to validation multiple files, the only difference is they have different date, for example:

```
file_2021_07_01.txt
file_2021_07_02.txt
...
file_2021_08_01.txt
```

I want to validate those 30 days files exist. Is there a way to do this batch validation without creating 30 validation activities?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array variable on the pipeline
- Use a Get Metadata activity set for Child Items
- Get the metadata activity's `output.childItems` into the variable
- You can then test `length(variables(yourVariable))` to check there are 30 files

If you need to check the filenames are what you expect, you'd need to loop through the childitems.

If it's one file per month-day rather than always 30 as your question implies, then you'll need some time intelligence also.